# Using different GPU types with SLURM on the same node

Tags: gpu, slurm, hpc

I'm setting up a GPU "cluster" used by a group of engineer as a pool of resources to train DL models on. We don't expect to use multiple GPUs per job.

From the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/gres.conf.html), it's seems possible to have different types of GPUs on a same node. But I often heard it was not recommended.

Any specific reason why one shouldn't have an heterogenous GPU configuration on the same compute node?

Note: In my case, it's mixing an A100 with 3 A10 GPUs.

Comment: Because people should care more about the load imbalance resulting from the different performance of the GPUs but also possibly with heterogeneous architecture (I am wondering if this is actually supported by the CUDA runtime). Using efficiently multiple GPU is already a mess, so using an heterogeneous set of GPU will likely not be supported by most application. You should expect inefficient execution time (bounded by the slowest GPU) and issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'll update the question but in our setup, the GPU resources are not meant to be combined. They constitute a pool of resource for DL model training.